# Como exibir um array na horizontal?

Tags: php, html

Não estou conseguindo imprimir um array na horizontal em uma página HTML. Como posso fazer isso?

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['nome']) && $_GET!=['nome']) {
    $lista_tarefa = array();
    $lista_tarefa['nome'] = $_GET['nome'];
}



if (isset($_GET['descricao'])) {
    $lista_tarefa['descricao'] = $_GET['descricao'];
} else {
    $lista_tarefa['descricao'] = '';
}
```

PHP+HTML:

```
  <table>

  <?php foreach ($lista_tarefa as $tarefa) : ?>

       <tr>
           <td> <?php echo $tarefa; ?> </td>
        </tr>

   <?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>
```

Comment: tem certeza que esse primeiro if esta certo? não entendi esse  `$_GET!=['nome']`

Comment: O certo é: **$_GET!=['nome']!=''**

Comment: Ainda parece estar errado.

Comment: Não, é assim mesmo rsrs. 
 
Mas, surgiu outro problema... Tenho 5 input="text" e quero adicionar 5 valores e ao chamar meu submit, imprimi-los em uma tabela de forma horizontal. Ok, isto consegui. Mas, quero adicionar mais 5, mais 5 e mais 5... Mas ao fazer isso ele imprimi ao lado, quero que ele desça e imprima na linha debaixo. Como faço isso?

Comment: Abra outra  pergunta. E se a resposta estiver certa. Marque como correta.

Answer (score 3):

Deixe apenas o "td" dentro do loop.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ErlonCharles isso é um resposta a pergunta, se esta certa ou errada, isso já é outra coisa.

Comment: Não é questão de certo ou errado, seria interessante ele mostrar também como fazer isso com base no código da pergunta e explicar os motivos disso, ou seja, fazer uma resposta mais completa. Assim como ela está ela é mais um comentário q uma resposta

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião é complicar o simples, de qualquer forma, a comunidade ou o próprio  autor irão selecionar a melhor resposta. A pessoa já fez o favor de dar a resposta, agora vocês querem que ela escreva um livro pra mover um if.

Comment: É exatamente isto, obrigado. Mas, surgiu outro problema... Tenho 5 input="text" e quero adicionar 5 valores e ao chamar meu submit, imprimi-los em uma tabela de forma horizontal. Ok, isto consegui. Mas, quero adicionar mais 5, mais 5 e mais 5... Mas ao fazer isso ele imprimi ao lado, quero que ele desça e imprima na linha debaixo. Como faço isso?